# Umbraco Template/Master Files Reappearing after Deletion in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, master-pages, umbraco

I know that the integration between umbraco and VS2010 isn't perfect.  For example, things linger in umbraco because it stores things in flat files like umbraco.config.  In general, when I delete things like document types or make certain kinds of changes to document properties in them, in VS I delete the umbraco.config, clean the solution and rebuilt before running the CMS.  After that, I know the db keeps some things around, so I go into the Settings section and delete the approprite document properties, etc.

That said, I haven't yet figured out where umbraco is storing certain master pages/templates since, when I delete certain ones of those, when I clean and rebuild, the files will reappear (thought not included in the project).  Can anyone tell me where the reference to these deleted templates lives in the umbraco SiteBuilder code so that I can get rid of them permanently?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a template within the Umbraco CMS itself, then this will not only delete the record in the database but it will also delete the physical file itself.

If you only delete the physical file, Umbraco will recreate the template based on the template record it has in the database.

Answer (score 0):

i found the best way to use VS 2010 with umbraco is to install this extension http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/visual-studio-2010-project-template which allows you to create the umbraco site as a VS project. This ensures any change you do to umbraco are picked up in visual studio as well and the best way to delete/create templates is to do it via umbraco as it creates references and and id to these in the database (if you do it in vs the umbraco settings that do this wont pick it up).

Comment: Provided you have NuGet in VS2010, by far the easiest way is to install Umbraco from NuGet. This will set Umbraco up as a project and install a separate NuGet pacakage with the binaries in so that they are referenced from the project correctly.